# Application Insights tiles (table) are not automatically refreshed on Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I've created a simple query using Kusto language in Application Insights. This query has been pinned to Azure Dashboard.

[image: Dashboard image]

I've noticed that there is no any automatic update applied for the table, moreover refresh button on the tile work only first time when you click on it.

[image: Refresh button image]

Here is the query pinned to Azure Dashboard:

```
traces
| order by timestamp desc nulls last 
| take 10
```

Based on information specified [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d80b16e0-b134-4af2-a856-0dd14d8f467c/tiles-on-dashboard-does-not-update-automatically?forum=ApplicationInsights) I expected that table should be refreshed every 5 minutes. But seems that the table is never refreshed.

Is there are automatic refresh exist for AI queries on Azure Dashboard? Actually I didn't find any mentioning about automatic refresh apart provided above link.

Comment: why don't you try with another simple query(with some other entities than traces) and see if refresh button works. If it does then the 5 minutes auto refresh is also likely to work. Then we prove that it s particular problem with traces collection . then it could be a different diagnosis

Comment: Blue Clouds, I've mentioned traces as an example. The same issue I had with different queries and collections. BTW I've had a conversation with Azure support engineers. They told me that there is no auto-refresh for tables from Analytics (Application Insights) and they are going to make some enhancements around that soon

Answer (score 1):

Metrics refresh depends on time range with minimum of five minutes. Logs refresh at one minute.

[Related documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations)

Regarding the refresh button on the tile, thanks for sharing the feedback on that. We have reached out to concerned team to look further into it. Will keep you updated on it.

Comment: I've had a conversation with Azure support engineers. They told me that there is no auto-refresh for tables from Analytics (Application Insights) and they are going to make some enhancements around that soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for it, you can create a Chrome Extension which hunts the Dashboard DOM and selectively clicks each refresh DIV. Here's the pertinent jquery code:

```
function doRefresh(){
    $( "div.azc-toolbarButton-container" ).each(
      function() {
        if ($( this ).attr( "title" ).indexOf("Refresh") >= 0)
          $( this ).trigger('click');
     });
}
```

I was able to do this. Added a 1 minute setInterval() and it appears to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Those are AnalyticsPart tiles,
they refresh automatically **every hour.**

Of course, you can initiate a refresh by clicking the refresh button.

Azure dashboard is planning to expose an automatic refresh pile that will enable the user to customize the refresh rate of the dashboard parts. One could then chose to customize the rate to 1 hour, 30 min, etc. AnalyticsPart may onboard to this new pile.
It's still in the designing stages of the azure team.

Comment: I suggest to check this out by pinning any analytics query to dashboard. Refresh is not working even after 1 hour.

Comment: The automatic refresh after 1 hour works for me, if you're still experiencing problems  please contact me on raronen@microsoft.com.

Comment: The manual refresh works the first time and afterwards it brings that data from the an entity cache. We should fix this. I'll update here once we do.

Comment: Updating we did.